# How how can i update pre-cached resources with google workbox?

Tags: javascript, workbox

i have migrated my own developed service worker to google workbox. All in all a great thing. Workbox just need's a few lines of code and is very powerful. :) My question is about pre-caching: I have a lot of files that i pre cache. Each entry of the pre cache list has a revision number.

But when i update the service worker and change the revision number of a single resource, workbox does not update it.

How can i force workbox to always use the latest version of a resource?

Comment: did you follow what described here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files?

Comment: Hello, yes i have readed through the docs :) I found a working solution for me in the meantime by myself. The problem in workbox is that the pre cached files are only updated on a force reload or when you close all the tabs and re-open the site again. For my PWA application it was important that the resources are always up to date when a new version is available. For that purpose i have implemented pusher.js with a custom event subscriber. When a update event is recieved by pusher.js the cached entry for resource XY will be cleared. And so workbox is forced to reload the resource by network.

Comment: Sounds a good solution:)